# How to join a table of result rows with a table containing some conditions as a varchar field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, join

I have a SQL function which I need to check its result rows with multiple dynamic conditions stored in a varchar field of another table, and get matched rows and conditions along with other info of the conditions.

I named the conditions table as `Strategy`, because I need to decide what to do with each row at next step, based on the conditions that it matched.

The entity class of conditions table is like this:

```
 public class Strategy
 {
     public decimal RowId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }        
     public string Conditions { get; set; }
 }
```

I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetRows] (@param) as TB
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Strategy] as ST 
Where [TB rows match in ST.Conditions]     --> ???
```

I thought about using sp_executesql but I am confused if I need to use a while loop and execute it once for each Strategy condition.
Also let me know if there is a way to do this using Entity Framework in the c# code.

Comment: Can you post the table definition (as a create statement) and some sample data (insert statements) along with the desired output? I think you may need dynamic here but it just isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you need to check the condition from the values from the [TB] that matches with your [Strategy] table? `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetRows] (@param) as TB
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Strategy] as ST ON ST.Conditions = TB.[Column]`. Do you have some examples from the data of your [Strategy] table and [TB] table?

Comment: @Flavio Francisco Yes, exactly. I need to check if values of the [TB] matches with some conditions like `value1>1000 and value2<>0` and then I will choose how to proccess that row. Also I do not need the rows that does not match non of the conditions.

Comment: You may need a `CASE WHEN` statement in your query. Please check this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: That's what I thought. Since you are storing processing logic in the data you are going to have to become intimately with dynamic sql.

Comment: @Sean Lange I don't care if dynamic conditions does not match the [TB] values. It is configured by admin, therefore it may be a little strange.

Comment: @Flavio Francisco So how can I do this with Case When ? Because it needs exact conditions and I have some string conditions stored in a table.

Comment: You need dynamic sql because you have the conditions in the table.

Comment: @Sean Lange Yes. So you mean that there is no way?

Comment: If you have things like "Value1 > 1000" stored in the table and that is the logic you want applied to the query you have to execute dynamic sql.

Comment: Would be nice if you put some scenarios in your question. Like some sample data from the table: TB; your table: Strategy and the expected results.

Comment: Yes, please post the table definition (create table statement) and a couple rows of sample data (insert statement) as well as the desired output.

Comment: @Sean Lange Oh Dynamic SQL. Sorry I didn't know that it is the name of what I said `using sp_executesql `. So I think you mean that I should dynamic sql to create a select statement with case when. I think it is good. Thanks.

Comment: @Flavio Frankly speaking I didn't create the table yet, so don't have any real data now. Maybe it was an early question :-). But I think I can post that as soon as I did everything. Thank you both.